# Superposition v/s Superimposition

Tags: optics, waves, superposition

What is the difference between '**superposition** of waves' and '**superimposition** of waves'?

Comment: I haven't heard [superimposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superimposition) used in a physics context. Perhaps a mis-speaking.

Comment: I’m familiar with “superposition” as a noun and “superimpose” as a verb, but the verb “superpose” and the noun “superimposition” both feel new to me. You remind me of [this lucifying table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhXHH.jpg) of strings which perhaps ought to be English-language words, based on an apparent pattern-formation rule, but mostly aren’t.

Comment: @user121330 Perhaps it was... Even I thought it was odd when I read it and googling didn't give me any results

Comment: @rob On another note... May I have the source for your "lucifying table"? I would like to include it in my project for English class. It just fits the theme so perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately that little table is “internet found art.” No idea where I found it.

Comment: Oh okay thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

from

https://wikidiff.com/superimposition/superposition

"As nouns the difference between superposition and superimposition is that superposition is the placing of one thing on top of another while superimposition is the placing of one image on top of another, especially placing a photograph over some other graphic."

So superimposition is more of a photography term.

Comment: That's what I thought too! I've only ever seen "superpose" being used with waves but recently my teacher frequently used "waves superimpose..." in a sentence and that's why I thought maybe 'superpose' and 'superimpose' could be synonyms in this context.